# Custom area borders/shading in Google Maps module

Tags: maps, plugins

I have a utilities client looking to allow their customers a way to determine which service area they belong to.

I want to allow the customer to search for their address and drop a pin in a Google Maps module that shows the service areas using shading or borders.

Is this kind of area marking possible with Google Maps? Are there any resources you can point me to to validate this?

Answer (score 1):

Where I work, we have something similar to this. We draw polygons for land areas for farmers. We use [Google Maps API Javascript simple polygon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-simple). It is also possible to change colors and add popovers and pins.